# Constant function and Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h$ be a function holomorphic in the region $D\subset \mathbb{C}$. Let $C\subset D$ a Jordan curve (rectifiable) with interior $D_C$ in $D$. Suppose that for each $z\in C$, $ \operatorname{Re}  h(z)= (\operatorname{Im} h(z))^2$. Show that $h$ is constant in $D$.

I have tried to consider the image $h(C)$ and its index (winding number) around of points in its complement. I would like to know: What do implies the Argument Principle on the image of $D_C$?

Comment: Yes Potato $C\subset D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: $h(D_C)\subset h(C).$

Choose $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus h(C).$ Note that $h(C)$ is compact and $z$ lies in the unbounded component of $h(C).$ Hence the winding number of $z$ with respect to $h(C)$, $n(h(C);z)=0.$ So from the formula $n(h(C);z)=\Sigma_1^nn(C;z_i),$ where $z_i$ are the preimages of $z$, we get that no $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus h(C)$ has preimage in $D_C.$ So $h(D_C)\subset h(C).$

By the claim, $h$ is constant by Open Mapping Theorem on $D_C$ and hence on $D.$

Comment: Why do you say that: z lies in the unbounded component of $h(C)$?. And When do you use the hypothesis: $ \operatorname{Re}  h(z)= (\operatorname{Im} h(z))^2$?

Comment: First of all note that the curve is a parabola. What is special about parabola is that if you remove it from the plane you have two unbounded components. Now the image h(C) lies in the parabola. Observe that basically it's a closed and bounded arc on the parabola. So if you consider the complement of h(C) there is only one component, the unbounded component.

Comment: Infact there is nothing special about parabola. You can choose any curve whose complement is the disjoint union of "only unbounded components" and then the above reasoning works. Thanks for asking.